# I connected an internal hdd using a SATA and it does not show in "This PC"

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, cmd.exe, lenovo-laptop, usb-to-sata

The internal Hdd when connected to PC via SATA does not show up in "This PC" so I opened the disk management it shows: Disk 1 unknown 465.76 GB not initialized, 465.76 GB Unallocated. When I right click and hit initialize disk 1 either MBR or GPT it shows "Data error (cyclic redundancy check)". I opened the DiskPart in CMD >list disk, >select disk 1, >clean (DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk), >Create partition primary (DiskPart encountered an error: The media is write protected), >attributes disk clear readonly (DiskPart has encountered an error: The request could not be performed because of an i/o device error. See the system event log for more information). To fix the cyclic redundancy error or the i/o error I got information from Google. Now if I want to run the chkdsk or sfc/scannow there is no volume so there are no letter assigned to the disk. So under DiskPart if I try to assign a letter it shows: the disk is not initialized.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The disk is dead, replace it.